# pass value from input to node js http request parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js

greeting kings

i have api request that have cors problem. I'm able to solve by using proxy setup using nodejs. Unfortunately im trying to pass certain query parameter from my main js to app.js(nodejs proxy) so my api can have certain value from main js. How to solve this or should point me where should i read more.below is my code

main js

```
const inputValue = document.querySelector('input').value

//this value is maybeline
```

app.js(node.js proxy)

```
const express = require('express')
const request = require('request');
const app = express()


app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    next();
})


app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    request(
        { url: 'https://makeup-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/products.json?brand=covergirl' },
        (error, response, body) => {
            if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
                return res.status(500).json({ type: 'error', message: err.message });
            }

            res.json(JSON.parse(body));
        }
    )
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5500

app.listen(5500,()=>console.log(`listening ${port}`))
```

I want to pass inputValue as query to api in app.js

as

`https://makeup-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/products.json?brand=${type}`

How to do it or point me any direction?

note:this api work withour cors problem.This is an example api..tq

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to confirm that your `main.js` runs in your user's browser? `app.js` obviously runs on a nodejs server.  You'll need to use [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or [xhr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) in your browser code to access your nodejs server and pass that `inputValue`. And, do use the [npm cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) package instead of trying to reinvent the flat tire.

Comment: Use req.query['brand'] to see the query param your /api got

Comment: Already fetch at app.js..will edit back.thanks for suggestion using npm cors..next time will use it..just right now i just want to look under the hood for first time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stringify` method from `qs` module.

```
const { stringify } = require("qs");

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
  request(
    {
      url: `https://makeup-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/products.json?${stringify(
        req.params
      )}`,
    }
        /// Rest of the code
      );
    });
```